# Jest test runner fails on certain characters in test string

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs

Let's say I write a Jest test case as:

```
test('encode bar', () => {
   let foo = encodeBar();
   expect(foo).toEqual("bar");
});
```

and then run it as:

```
node node_modules/.bin/jest --no-coverage -t "encode bar"
```

It works fine.

However if I add a '+' sign to my test case string as:

```
test('encode + bar', () => {
   let foo = encodeBar();
   expect(foo).toEqual("bar");
});
```

and then run it as:

```
node node_modules/.bin/jest --no-coverage -t "encode + bar"
```

Jest will fail to run the test.
Is this documented/configurable somewhere?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Jest to write an actual answer, but does this part of the docs help? [regex for test files](https://jestjs.io/docs/cli#jest-regexfortestfiles)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-t` ([--testNamePattern](https://jestjs.io/docs/cli#--testnamepatternregex)) expects regex, escape `+` with backslash like this: `-t "encode \+ bar"`